# Prove the probability of the graph containing a triangle is 0 as n→∞

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G$ a random graph with $n$ vertices.

Every vertex appears in the graph with a probability of $\frac{f(n)}{n}$ ($n$ is the number of vertices so the distribution is uniform),

while $f(n)$ is a function satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n) = 0$.

> Prove the probability of the graph containing a triangle is $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

My try:

Using the union bound we can bound this probability with $$\binom{n}{3}\cdot \left(\frac{f(n)}{n}\right)^3$$ which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

I was wondering if there's a more elegeant or direct or any other way to solve this one.

Comment: That seems pretty elegant to me, I'd state it in terms of expectation but it's all good.

Comment: By any chance is $f(n)$ actually the probability of each *edge* being present? (Your solution is technically valid either way, but a random graph in which the number of vertices tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ has no triangles for much more boring reasons.)