# Why $\mathbb{P}(\text{vertex $1$ is part of a triangle}) \to 0$ in an Erdös-Rényi graph, as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, convergence-divergence, random-graphs

Let $G(n, \lambda/n)$ be an Erdös-Rényi random graph. I need to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\text{vertex $1$ is part of a triangle}) = 0.$$

([This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751995/prove-the-probability-of-the-graph-containing-a-triangle-is-0-as-n%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E) also asks a similar question as mine)

Below is my attempt.

Let $[n]$ denote the set of vertices of $G$ and $x , y \in [n]\backslash\{1\}$. Let $\Delta(1, x,y)$ be the sets of all possible triangles in $G$ such that vertex $1, x$ and $y$ form a triangle. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{vertex $1$ is part of a triangle}) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{x, y \in [n]\backslash\{1\}}|\Delta(1, x, y)| \geq 1\right)\\
\leq \sum_{x, y \in [n]\backslash\{1\}}\mathbb{E}[|\Delta(1, x, y)|]
$$
The last inequality is obtained used the bound for union and Markov's inequality.
This leaves me with computing the expected number of triangles in $G(n, \lambda/n)$. I have seen on the internet that the expected number of triangles in Erdös-Rényi graph is
$${n \choose 3}\frac{\lambda^3}{n^3}.$$
But shouldn't in my case
$$\mathbb{E}[|\Delta(1, x, y)|] = {n-1 \choose 2}\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}?$$
If so, it means that
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{vertex $1$ is part of a triangle}) \leq (n-2)(n-3){n-1 \choose 2}\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}$$
which does not go to $0$ if $n \to \infty$.
So I am not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $ |\Delta(1, *, \tilde\star)|$ the number of triangles that contain node 1. For each triple $1,x,y$, the chance that all three edges connecting them are selected in $G(n.\lambda/n)$ is $(\lambda/n)^3$. Thus  $$\mathbb{E}[|\Delta(1, *, \tilde\star)|] = {n-1 \choose 2}\frac{\lambda^3}{n^3} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty \,. $$

Comment: So I don't need the $\sum_{x,y\in [n]\backslash\{1\}}$?

Comment: The sum over unordered pairs $x,y$ gives the factor ${n-1 \choose 2}$.